# Google Chrome Taskbar Notification Icon

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I'm using Google Chrome for Facebook Chat and was wondering if there was any way to show a notification on the Windows 7 superbar for when I get a message on Facebook?

Similar to Firefox 4 where you have a pinned tab, and the tab has a glow when you have a new message.

Comment: Should *probably* go to webapps.SE, I voted to move it there. But maybe not?

Comment: @slhck question's about Chrome showing up a notification on Windows task(super)bar, not about facebook. I don't see how it should be on Web Apps

Answer (score 1):

The tab glow in Firefox4 happens when the page's title changes, the browser which has an event listener will give the tab a glow effect. As far as chrome goes, the taskbar notifications are available in the browser's [extensions API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html) so it's a different ball game. The [Facebook chat extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ggekjaligipajhljkbemifjgmlpcfkao?hl=en) is one which shows such desktop notifications may that could be what you're looking for

Comment: It's not perfect but it'll do! Thanks Avis.

Comment: @Mozazjnr Welcome :)